# Solr web UI dashboard not displaying

Tags: solr

I am really new to Solr and I have successfully create a core and was following the tutorial.

Environment:

- Java 1.8
- Windows 32bit
- Browser: IE
- Solr 5.1.0

I use the following 2 commands

```
bin\solr start
bin\solr create -c demo
```

But when I launch the solr ui, it comes out with a pop up saying `there exists no core with name "~index"` and the dashboard is not displayed

I check the solr status and the port I using is the default port:8983.

May I know what could be the problem?

Comment: No one has the answer or some recommended solutions? Thought stackoverflow is a huge community with experts.

Comment: What is the URL when the solr admin complains about `~index` not existing?

Comment: @cpburnz localhost:8983/solr